# Run Selenium web-driver with C# in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to setup an environment to run selenium with C# in Ubuntu. I am using Visual Studio Code as my IDE. Everything else is setup but I am getting errors constantly.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace c_sharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Url = "http://quotes.toscrape.com/";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the complete error message I get:

```
/home/sagunsh/c-sharp/c-sharp.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 
'Selenium.WebDriver 3.5.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
/home/sagunsh/c-sharp/c-sharp.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Selenium.WebDriver 3.5.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
Starting ChromeDriver 2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8) on port 51621
Only local connections are allowed.

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.

   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.get_DynamicCodeGeneration()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.get_ReflectionDelegateFactory()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.GetDefaultCreator(Type createdType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.InitializeContract(JsonContract contract)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateDictionaryContract(Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.Command.get_ParametersAsJsonString()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at c_sharp.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/sagunsh/c-sharp/Program.cs:line 11
```

I have wasted the last 12 hours to figure out where did I go wrong. I am a python developer but for some reason need to use c# now and I am completely new to it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: are u set path of chromedriver

Comment: yes path is set, every other thing is fine since I do a lot of selenium stuffs with python too.

Comment: Webdriver.dll is missing i Guess

Answer (score -1):

Also look like `Webdriver.dll` is missing.

To fix it

1. Click on the `Webdriver dll` reference
2. In the properties window make sure `copylocal = true`

I think you have to set path of `chromedriver`, try this

```
namespace c_sharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"E:\chrome\chromedriver_32.exe");
            driver.Url = "http://quotes.toscrape.com/";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using it on ubuntu. Does that make sense?

Comment: I hve to check it dear let me try